# Too Many Rerenders - Storing useLocation().state variable in a useState() variable

Tags: reactjs

The URL contains an ID of a project. If a user navigated to the projects page from a projects overview page, the project info would already be stored in `useLocation().state`, however, if they access this hyperlink from outside, `useLocation().state` would be `null`.

I first declare `coverImageUrl` and `setCoverImageURL` state variables, set them to `null`, and then want to either manually fetch them if they haven't been passed as parameters, or load them from `useLocation().state`.

Under current testing scenarios I'm dealing only with situations where these parameters are passed however, I am getting a `too many re-renders` error and I'm not sure why.

Code:

```
const state = useLocation().state
let project = null
const [coverImageURL, setCoverImageURL] = useState('')

if(!!state && 'project' in state && 'coverImageURL' in state) { // parameters passed
    project = state.project
    console.log(`parameters supplied, coverImageURL: ${state.coverImageURL}`)
    setCoverImageURL(state.coverImageURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameters are passed in and `useLocation().state` has value, your condition is true. This is what you expect.

The problem is setting state causes a re-render of the component (`setCoverImageUrl()`). When the component re-renders, your condition is still true. This means you set state again, and therefore re-render.

This is why you see "too many re-renders", because you have an infinite loop.

To fix this, put your condition and state update in a `useEffect` that only triggers when the component first mounts:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if(!!state && 'project' in state && 'coverImageURL' in state) { // parameters passed
    project = state.project
    console.log(`parameters supplied, coverImageURL: ${state.coverImageURL}`)
    setCoverImageURL(state.coverImageURL)
  }
}, []);
```